# c# reportviwer передача параметров в отчет

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

Здравствуйте, назрел вопрос по передаче параметров в отчет.

```
List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("имя_параметра", " "));
form2.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

Так я стандартно передаю в отчет, но когда параметров много прописывать имя каждого затратно, можно как либо через цикл по индексу какому-нибудь внести.

Comment: Вторую строку обвернуть в цикл - и заполнять.

Comment: @nick_n_a, так все равно придется прописывать названия параметров, только в строке

Comment: Всё зависит от ваших пожеланий, так как вы *дополнительно* не говорите что хотите, то покажу вам *общую* форму: `for (int i = 0; i < f_length(); i++) parameters.Add(f_name(i), f_value(i));` Список параметров можно взять как из класса "dataset" (если он нормально сделан), так и из самого шаблона отчётов.

Comment: Ещё можно пары name-value получить из `Request.Params`

Comment: @nick_n_a, Спасибо, буду разбираться.